# How can I toggle between dashboards of sharepoint with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, sharepoint

I need to present different dashboards on one screen. They need to pass in a certain amount of time.

Locally, I was able to use "os.startfile" with Python. I was able to switch between tabs because the computer wouldn't let me open a tab that was already open.

Now, I need the spreadsheets to be removed from SharePoint so that we can update them online. Using startfile it opens several tabs in a row. And in reality, what I need is to switch tabs after they are open.

The path is an internet link.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: why list multiple versions of python ?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal of opening and switching between different dashboards hosted on SharePoint, you can use a combination of libraries like selenium for web automation and time for handling delays. Here's a simple example in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

dashboard_links = [
    'https://yoursharepointsite/dashboard1',
    'https://yoursharepointsite/dashboard2',
    'https://yoursharepointsite/dashboard3',
]

driver = webdriver.Chrome()  

try:
    for link in dashboard_links:
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
        driver.get(link)


except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    driver.quit()
```